# Conflicting Favicons

Tags: android, browser, favicon

My Blogger site generates the following line:

```
<link href='http://www.mtscollective.com/favicon.ico' rel='icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
```

And I've also added the following line for Android to use when the site is saved to the home screen:

```
<link href='http://cdn.mtscollective.com/images/android/icon-196.png' rel='icon' sizes='196x196'/>
```

The problem is that sometimes Chrome and Firefox use these interchangeably, but I only want them to use the first line. Is it possible to control this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Firefox and Chrome tend to favor PNG pictures over `favicon.ico`.](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility#not_root) So you should also declare a 16x16 PNG picture, along with your existing 196x196 picture.

Also note that Firefox uses the last declared PNG picture (this is [bug 751712](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=751712)). Make sure you declare the 16x16 picture *last*:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/path/to/icons/favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/path/to/icons/favicon-196x196.png" sizes="196x196">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/path/to/icons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
```

Finally, both Firefox and Chrome lack support for the `sizes` attribute. As a consequence, during the first visit, they will load both PNG pictures (these are [bug 751712 (FireFox)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=751712) and [issue 324820 (Chrome)](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=324820)). This is not a serious issue, but good to know this.

Comment: If both browsers don't support the `sizes` attribute, what's the benefit of using it in the 16x16 line?

Comment: Chrome does not check the sizes attribute, but it selects the icon with the most suitable resolution (16x16 in classic desktop environment). And Firefox picks the last PNG icon. But the other browsers (such as Android Chrome) are smart enough to load only the 196x196 icon, with the help of the sizes attributes it encounters.

Comment: I understand, but if neither Chrome or Firefox support the `sizes` attribute, and since they're the main browsers that I'm targeting the favicon at, do I need to add `sizes="16x16"`? Thanks

Comment: Well, I think it is better to declare it but I can't be 100% sure since I didn't test what follows: Android Chrome is one of your target. If you do not set `sizes=16x16`, it finds a 196x196 icon and... another icon. What does it do? Does it ignore this unspecified icon? Does it load it to figure out its size? Unless you explicitly test this case, I advice you not to omit `sizes=16x16`.

Comment: Yes, I wondered the same thing, but I assumed that Android Chrome would settle for the 196x196 icon once it finds it. I'll leave it in. Thanks again